# How to programmatically open a child view on a specified monitor in universal windows platform app?

Tags: uwp, multiple-monitors

In a Universal Windows Platform app, is it possible to programmatically create a second view (which is possible) but also show it on a secondary monitor (or third.. )?? How would I do that?

**Update**
I've looked at the Projection sample but that seems to only allow one secondary view to be projected. Whenever a new view is created and projected, the prior one is closed. Is there anyway to have multiple over multiple monitors?

**Update**
So I am able to get Hwnd (thanks to SO) of a UWP CoreWindow object. Unfortunately, even the top level hwnd of CoreWindow still doesn't let me manipulate the outer-most UWP Window Chrome. Looks like there's something else that sits on top of top-level hwnd of a CoreWindow. Some DirectX component, perhaps?

So ultimately, how do I manipulate a UWP window beyond the basics of maximizing, minimizing, etc, and be able to take a UWP window, put it on any monitor of choice, and maximize it, by code?? And this app is built targeting desktop, not ARM.

Comment: Hope this [sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Projection-sample-526b3c1d) helps. Although it is for 8.1, the `ProjectionManager` and `ApplicationViewSwitcher` are also available on UWP.

Comment: Just for complement of @kennyzx 's comment, this is a official [Projection sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Projection) for UWP.